# How to Assert Dictionary in c# nunit?

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

Do you know how I can Assert two dictionaries of type

```
Dictionary<string,MyClass>
```

in my Unit test project?

I tried with CollectionsAssert but it didn' work for me.I guess that it takes to simple Dictionaries as parameters(e.g. Dictionary).I guess that the problem for me comes from the second parameter of the dictionary.Do you know how I can assert those two dictionaries?

Comment: I dont know of any special assert for this, maybe you have to implement your own Comparer for your `MyClass` and use `Assert.AreEqual`

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it out of the box. I usually use [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) for more complicated assertions. It can detect your test framework and throw those specific assertion exceptions so it's easy to integrate into an existing project.

Answer (score 4):

You don't say what you want to assert about the two dictionaries, but I am assuming it's that they are equal.

Beginning with NUnit 3.0, you can assert that two dictionaries are equal like this...

`Assert.That(dictionary1, Is.EqualTo(dictionary2));`

This assertion checks
1. That the dictionaries contain the same number of entries.
2. That the dictionaries contain exactly the same keys.
3. That the values for each key are equal.

The third step depends on the definition of equality included in your class, if it has one. If you have not overloaded equality for the class, then object equality will, of course, be used.

If this is not enough information, please edit your question, which is unfortunately pretty vague. Saying you want to "assert" two objects has no meaning unless you specify what you want to assert about them.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to assert both key and value of dictionary.

Comment: I want to also assert MyClass object value of dictionary.

Comment: The example code I gave does assert that the keys are identical and the corresponding values are equal... see edit.